Calculate mixed second partial derivative
Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with continuous partial derivatives. It is given in addition that:
[ f'x (3,9) = f'y (3,9) = f''{xx} (3,9) = f''{yy} (3,9) = 1 ]
Define $g(x, y) = f(x^2 y, x y^2)$. Calculate the mixed second partial derivative $g_{xy}(1, 3)$.
The answer is 113
I've tried using the chain rule, but I could only figure out $g_{x}(1, 3)$.
How should I use the chain rule with second partial derivative?


I've tried using the chain rule, but I could only figure out $g'_x(1,3)$
. How should I use the chain rule with second partial derivative?

Don't calculate anything at $(x,y)=(1,3)$ until the final step.
Let $u=x^2y, v=xy^2$, so $g(x,y)=f(u,v)$, and ...
You should have that $g'_x(x,y) = u'_x~f'_u(u,v) +v'_x~f'_v(u,v)$ by chain rule , so the next step is to apply the product rule.
$\qquad\begin{align}g''_{xy}(x,y) &= (u'_x~f'_u(u,v) +v'_x~f'_v(u,v))'_{y}\\&=u''_{xy}~f'_u(x,y)+u'_x~(f'_u(u,v))'_y+v'_x~(f'_v(u,v))'_y+v''_{xy}~f'_v(x,y)\end{align}$
Next, apply the chain rule to the middle two terms.  After that, you may evaluate at the particular point.

[Note: You will need the mixed partial derivative of $f$, which you don't seem to have been given (unless you missed copying that).]
